# Masking the logs of kafka connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have property file in which there is some secrets(credentials) and certificates, i don't want to log them.
So is there any way to put that credentials somewhere else or not log them.
Do we have something called masking in apache kafka..?

Comment: Which setting are you referring to? Why are you logging credentials?

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using KSQL for streaming queries you use the masking function `MASK()`.

```
CREATE STREAM MASKED_PURCHASES AS 
  SELECT  MASK(CUSTOMER_NAME) AS CUSTOMER_NAME, 
          MASK_RIGHT(DATE_OF_BIRTH,12) AS DATE_OF_BIRTH, 
          ORDER_ID, PRODUCT, ORDER_TOTAL_USD, TOWN, COUNTRY 
  FROM PURCHASES;
```

---

```
ksql> SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH, PRODUCT, ORDER_TOTAL_USD FROM MASKED_PURCHASES LIMIT 1;
    Xxxxxx-Xxxxxx | 1908-03-nnXnn-nn-nnX | Langers - Mango Nectar | 5.80
```

Documentation source is [here](https://www.confluent.io/stream-processing-cookbook/ksql-recipes/data-masking/).